# How can I use Spybot?

Tags: spybot-sd

I have installed Spybot on my laptop which I own now 3 weeks only on a friend's advice.
I can see the program in my list of programs.  I followed steps and have a printout of the tutorial page.  I need this in order to start to use the program.

But I do not know what a host program is.  I do not know what an advertising robot is.  I do not know what a usage trail is.  The phrase "if you are using a proxy" appears.

I can not go from the tutorial until I can get a translation into basic English.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

now by spybot, i'm assume you're using [spybot s&d](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/tutorial/index.html) - I don't find any of those terms there. If you're using a proxy, you'd have a server name you need to input there - if you weren't asked to set one up (usually in a school setting) you probably can leave it out.

In any case, a link to the specific tutorial you're using would help.